# Why do I need an explicit ToString() when using a conditional operator?

Tags: c#, linq, conditional-operator

I've got the following code to compose a simple SOAP Post form data value:

```
     var postParameters = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
           { "someNumber", "100" },
           { "someString", "Hello World" }
        };

     var resultWhenNotInConditional = 
        postParameters
           .Keys
           .Zip(postParameters.Values, 
               (key, value) => string.Format("{0}={1}", key, value))
           .Aggregate<string, string>(null,
              (prev, next) =>
              (prev != null)
                 ? string.Format("{0}&{1}", prev, next)
                 : next);
```

which works as designed, viz

```
resultWhenNotInConditional = "someNumber=100&someString=Hello World"
```

However, when I wrap this in a conditional operator to do a null check, like so:

```
     var resultWhenInConditional = 
        (postParameters != null)
        ? postParameters
           .Keys
           .Zip(postParameters.Values, 
                (key, value) => string.Format("{0}={1}", key, value))
           .Aggregate<string, string>(null,
              (prev, next) =>
              (prev != null)
                 ? string.Format("{0}&{1}", prev, next)
                 : next)
        : string.Empty;
```

The `resultWhenInConditional` seems to be always null, irrespective of whether `postParameters` is set to null or to a valid `Dictionary<string, string>`. (Changing the `var` to an explicit `string` also has no effect).

The only way I can fix this is by adding `ToString()` after the `Aggregate`, viz:

```
     var resultWhenInConditional = 
       (postParameters != null)
        ? postParameters
           .Keys
           .Zip(postParameters.Values, 
                (key, value) => string.Format("{0}={1}", key, value))
           .Aggregate<string, string>(null,
              (prev, next) =>
              (prev != null)
                 ? string.Format("{0}&{1}", prev, next)
                 : next)
           .ToString() // R# warns this is redundant
        : string.Empty;
```

So my question is, why do I need to add the additional `.ToString()` when inside the conditional operator?

- Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2010 Version 10.0.40219.1 SP1Rel
- Microsoft .NET Framework Version 4.0.30319 SP1Rel

**Edit**

Thanks for the feedback!

To confirm that this is just an aberration - the VS IDE is reporting the variable as NULL (in the mouse hover + Immediate Window), 
but only when debugging the unit tests individually with the R# NUnit test runner. Debugging under the console App reports the value correctly in the IDE.

i.e. This only happens when debugging, under the Resharper NUnit TestRunner.

As soon as the variable is accessed by further code (e.g. `Assert` / `Console.Writeline` etc), it is clear that the value is NOT actually null.

I've added a [console app to GitHub](https://github.com/nonnb/FunnyGoingsOnWithR-andNUnit)
and a [screenshot here](https://raw.github.com/nonnb/FunnyGoingsOnWithR-andNUnit/master/IDEReportsAsNull.png)

None of the unit tests actually fail, i.e. the value isn't actually null :-)

- R# 7.1.3 C# Edition (2224)
- NUnit 2.6.1.12217

Comment: Your `resultWhenInConditional` works fine for me in VS2012 / .NET 4 without .ToString();

Comment: For me, too! Seems to be ok.

Comment: Me too. Please show a short but *complete* program (a console app) which definitely, definitely demonstrates the problem. Note that `resultWhenInConditional` *will* be `null` if `postParameters` is non-null but *empty*. Perhaps that's what you're actually seeing?

Comment: Thanks very much to everyone for the feedback - turns out it is just reported as null on the IDE when running under R#'s NUnit test runner. The value isn't actually null. I've updated the post.

Comment: Just curious... What would a .GetType().ToString() show if you add it after the Aggregate<...>(...) ?

Comment: Adding the `GetType()` to the code returns `{Name = "String" FullName = "System.String"}` as expected I guess. But in the R# / NUnit / Debugging setup however, `resultWhenInConditional.GetType().ToString()` returns `'((object)(resultWhenInConditional))' is null .. string`.

Comment: `Aggregate` can be invoked simpler than you do it, like this: `Aggregate((a, b) => a + "&" + b)`. Is there a reason to do it that way?

Comment: @AndreiTanas - Thanks for spotting this - absolutely right, I didn't need to use the seed overload for the fold. But same result, `resultWhenInConditional` shows as Null when debugging in the IDE. Now that I know that it isn't really null, I'm able to move on :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To confirm that this is just an aberration - the VS IDE is reporting the variable as NULL (in the mouse hover + Immediate Window), 
but only when debugging the unit tests individually with the R# NUnit test runner. Debugging under the console App reports the value correctly in the IDE.

i.e. This only happens when debugging, under the Resharper NUnit TestRunner.

As soon as the variable is accessed by further code (e.g. `Assert` / `Console.Writeline` etc), it is clear that the value is NOT actually null.

I've added a [console app to GitHub](https://github.com/nonnb/FunnyGoingsOnWithR-andNUnit)
and a [screenshot here](https://raw.github.com/nonnb/FunnyGoingsOnWithR-andNUnit/master/IDEReportsAsNull.png)

None of the unit tests actually fail, i.e. the value isn't actually null :-)

- R# 7.1.3 C# Edition (2224)
- NUnit 2.6.1.12217