# Unable to parse string to integer value

Tags: c#, string, integer, appsettings

I really don't have the idea on why I am getting `0` value on this:

[image]

But this code works well:

```
int val = Convert.ToInt32("1546");
```

Here is the appsetting:

```
<add key="PesoPayMerchantId" value="​1546"/>
```

Any idea?

**Edit1**

I want to get the integer value of `"1546"`, but it fails to work.
Here is the code for getting appsetting:

```
    public static string GetConfigurationString(string appSettingValue)
    {
        return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[appSettingValue];
    }
```

I have tried your suggestions, and this is the result:

[image]
[image]
[image]

The string value is correct `("1546")`, but it can't be parse to integer. What is happening here?

**Edit 2**

I am very sure that the value of:

```
<add key="PesoPayMerchantId" value="​1546"/>
```

is really a combination of numbers `"1546"`
But when I try to re-write the string value using `Immediate Window` it can now be parsed. But still I can't figure out the very reason of this `Bug`?

[image]

**Edit 3**

Finally, it works now, thanks to [Johnny](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3176201/johnny)

What I did is, I re-write the whole, `<add key="PesoPayMerchantId" value="1546"/>` and it can now be parsed. Thanks for all your help. :D

Comment: you are sure that id is 0 from the PesoPayMerchantId return value? Are you running this from a Release build? The debug bits misalign easily when things are optimized.

Comment: You should always check bool TryParse() result.

Comment: If TryParse fails the id value will be zero, so you should check if TryParse() is true upon execution.

Comment: Did you use mutithreading? Also change int.TryParse with double.TryParse and show result.

Comment: Check the actual result by `Console.WriteLine` (as opposed to what the IDE tells you the value is during debug) - I had a similar [weird issue here using the R# test runner](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19026872/why-do-i-need-an-explicit-tostring-when-using-a-conditional-operator)

Comment: The error is so strange. Please try `Int32.Parse()` method. Does it work?

Comment: This is interesting, u check with a hard coded value instead of value from appsettings and inform the reult

Comment: @Forte_201092 No, it doesn't work. It throws exception. I just gave up on this and use string value instead. Thanks to all.

Comment: @StuartLC I used `Debug.WriteLine(val)` and it output `1546`, which I think is a valid string. But still parsing it to integer fails.

Comment: The only way I can reproduce your problem is assign the value "l546" where the "l" is actually "L" in lower case. It looks pretty like "1" (one) but it is not. Try to reenter the value in the appSettings.

Comment: @Johnny I am very sure that it was `1` not `'l'` :)

Comment: @fiberOptics Did you re-enter the value?

Comment: Check if there is any space or other characters in the App setting value and trim it. If you are sure that there is not, then use Int.TryParse().

Comment: @fiberOptics I think there might be something in the string, and that is why you should re-type the whole value string. With the I-beam staying within the string (say between 15 and 46), then if you hold the Alt key and press 1, 2, 7, an invisible DEL char is inserted, and the same problem will occur. In this case, I won't call it a "bug".

Comment: You should loop through the string and print out each char code to make sure there are four characters only and that they are the codes you would expect for those numbers.

Comment: @Johnny I re-write the "1546", nothing happen, but when I re-write the whole `<add key="PesoPayMerchantId" value="1546"/>` it works now. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer would be, re-write the config.
As I remember, I just `copied and paste` `"1546"` from a pdf file.
So lesson learned, don't be too lazy on typing values.

Additional Information:
I also remember that, I did copy and `paste` on `gmail` `(google Chrome)` and I found out that the text I copied contains `hidden characters` at the beginning.

Comment: Copy/paste from PDF can be problematic. Maybe worth mentioning viewer/OS - I have had similar problems with evince document viewer under Linux.

Comment: LOL! Now I know the reason. Because you copy, the quotation mark is different from typing and it's not acceptable in config file.

Answer (score 2):

I can only think that you are experiencing some kind of weird globalization / Culture specific problem.

Given that you know the exact format of the number, you might try the `Int32.TryParse Method (String, NumberStyles, IFormatProvider, Int32)` [overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zf50za27%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), e.g.:

```
int.TryParse(val, NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out id);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would inspect the return value of Try.Parse.

From documentation:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx

```
      int number;
      bool result = Int32.TryParse(value, out number);
      if (result)
      {
         Console.WriteLine("Converted '{0}' to {1}.", value, number);         
      }
      else
      {
         if (value == null) value = ""; 
         Console.WriteLine("Attempted conversion of '{0}' failed.", value);
      }
```

Comment: I agree with this approach more as the Boolean return will let you know if the parsing failed or not, the 0 could just be the default value because the parsing failed or it could in actual fact be "0" that is converted into 0.

Comment: @TGH the result is false, but why?

Answer (score 1):

This test Assert's always correctly:

```
namespace SOWTests
{
    using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

    [TestClass]
    public class PTests
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void PTest()
        {
            string val = "1546";

            int id;
            int.TryParse(val, out id);

            Assert.AreEqual(1546, id);
        }
    }
}
```

So problem not in this part of code. It's maybe altered by some debugging/profiling part of your code. Or maybe there some stack corruption from unmanaged call.